# Filter packets sent via HTTP to a port other then 80?

Tags: http, wireshark, tcpdump

I have a database communicating on port 7474 via HTTP (sigh), and I want to debug the queries sent to / from it. However, a filter such as

```
http.request.method == "POST"
```

Filters out every post message sent to other ports.

---

Originally, I thought that the filtering syntax is shared in `tcpdump` and `Wireshark`, but it doesn't matter to me which tool to use, as long as it works :)

Comment: I'm not sure tcpdump's capture filters parse HTTP at all. If you're asking about Wireshark/tshark's *read* filters, that's a somewhat different thing.

Comment: @grawity Umm... I thought they were the same :) Well, Wireshark then, that's what I'm using. But if there's some way to do this via tcpdump, that's fine too, whichever gets me there.

Comment: There are two places where filtering happens, and they have different syntaxes – "capture filter" (the same in both Wireshark and tcpdump) determines what gets captured at all, and "read filter" (only in Wireshark) determines what gets shown when browsing an existing or running capture.

Comment: @grawity well, tcpdump can check for particular byte values so maybe it can in theory check if http request is a POST, even if tcpdump doesn't have 'HTTP related keywords' in its 'instruction set'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the connection isn't using any of the standard HTTP ports, you will have to tell Wireshark manually to dissect it as HTTP.

Right-click on any packet sent to port 7474, select "Decode As", then choose "Destination (→7474)" in the Transport tab. Select HTTP in the protocol list.

Comment: Yup, your answer combined with @nik filter did the trick. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

You need to add in the TCP Port filter,

```
tcp.dstport == 7474 and http.request.method == "POST"
```

more at the [wireshark manual page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html).

Comment: -1  his subject says tcpdump. If he wants other than tcpdump(as his comment suggests) then you or he or somebody, should correct the subject.  But writing an answer that doesn't match the subject seems like a bad answer to me.

Comment: Nope, this didn't do it. Sorry.

Comment: @barlop, OP has already tagged the question `wireshark`.

Comment: @nik ok and subject ok now too, -1 removed.

Comment: @wxvw, Can you please tell us what you do get with this filter? It is supposed to filter all POST packets to the TCP Destination Port 7474. If you have a specific destination IP address at hands, that can be added in too -- `and ip.dst == a.b.c.d`, see the manual link.

Comment: I really just pasted it as is into Wireshark's filter input box, after I certainly sent a request to the server and also got a response, but nothing showed up in the main window. The IP address is rather non-spcific in my case... that's  my localhost.